# Can Frida be used to trace all APIs of an Android app?

Tags: android, frida

I want to inquire if I can use frida to get a trace of all APIs called by an Android app at runtime. Frida has a tool called frida-trace but I haven't been able to find a regex to indicate hooking any java API invoked. I tried the following but I am not sure it is the right approach (Frida prints the message it is tracing 0 functions).

```
 $ frida-trace \
     -U \
     -f com.myapplixation \
     --runtime=v8 \
     -j '*!*.*'
```

Is it possible with Frida to get a trace of all java / android APIs called by an Android app ?

Comment: I don't thing you will manage to find one or even ten regex for the Android API as the API is not based on a pattern but "grown chaotic". You may have better success writing a program or script that generates a Frida script from the Android API jar file include in Android SDK. But some of the crashes in there are interfaces that Frida has problems hiking them so some times it may be necessary to hook the undocumented implementation classes instead.

Comment: what do you mean by android api if you mean all java methods and classes then the answer is probably no frida is stable but not that stable it will definitely crash the app